# Как вывести на экран элементы списка, с помощью цикла while, чтоб каждый элемент был с новой строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Вот похожий код, но с помощью цикла for, а мне нужно с while.**

```
num = input()[::-1]           
arr = [int(x) for x in str(num)]

for elem in arr:
    print('{}'.format(elem))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь делается ввод с клавиатуры целого числа, элементы которого разворачиваются в обратном порядке с помощью среза **num = input()[::-1]**.

И целое число преобразуется в список, для того чтоб сделать его итерируемым
**arr = [int(x) for x in str(num)]**

Чем более лаконичный (краткий) код будет в ответе - тем лучше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модифицируя ваш код, предлагаю такой вариант:

```
num = input()[::-1]           
arr = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
count, len_arr = 0, len(arr)

while count != len(arr):
    print(arr[count])
    count += 1
```

Но в целом поставленную задачу можно решить и таким образом:

```
num = int(input())
while num != 0:
    print(num % 10)
    num //= 10
```